# Conversion of 3D point cloud data in .bin file to .pcd file

Tags: python, c++, visualization, point-cloud-library, bin

I have **.bin file** containing **3D Point Cloud - 32 bit floating point** ASL data. The data for each frame is stored in planar form - **x y z and intensity coordinates for 100x220 pixels**.

I want to convert this data to **pcd** file for visualization in **pcl**. Can you help me with the **C++/Python** code?

```
def bin_to_pcd(binFileName):
    size_float = 8
    list_pcd = []
    with open(binFileName, "rb") as f:
        byte = f.read(size_float * 4)
        while byte:
            x, y, z, intensity = struct.unpack("ffff", byte)
            list_pcd.append([x, y, z])
            byte = f.read(size_float * 4)
    np_pcd = np.asarray(list_pcd)
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np_pcd)
    return pcd
```

*This code gives me an error : **unpack requires a buffer of 16 bytes***

If I change the size_float to 4, i get a pcd file but the visualization is incorrect as shown :

[image]

Comment: it looks like signed data is converted to unsigned data.

Comment: If I look at the [documentation for Vector3dVector](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.utility.Vector3dVector.html) it says "Convert float64 numpy array of shape (n, 3) to Open3D format.". Your floats are 32 bit (`size_float` should definitely be 4). I think a conversion from float32->float64 is needed.

Comment: Can you help me with the conversion